# C++ won't let me use a struct as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Perhaps it is a header problem of sorts... But this is what's happening:

The compiler is giving me an error on the line:

```
Queue<Email> mailbox;
```

This is the error:

```
..\EmailSystem.h:25: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Queue' with no type
..\EmailSystem.h:25: error: expected `;' before '<' token
```

Queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_

#include <string>
#include "EmailSystem.h"

...

template <class B>
class Queue {
 ...
};

#endif /* QUEUE_H_ */
```

Queue.cpp:

```
#include "Queue.h"

...

template class Queue<Email>;
```

EmailSystem.h:

```
#ifndef EMAILSYSTEM_H_
#define EMAILSYSTEM_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Queue.h"

struct Email {
    ...
};

struct User {
    std::string name;
    Queue<Email> mailbox;
};

...

#endif /* EMAILSYSTEM_H_ */
```

Comment: Also, any particular reason you're avoiding `std::deque` or `std::queue`?

Comment: For educational purposes, heh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a circular include. `Queue.h` includes `EmailSystem.h` and `EmailSystem.h` includes `Queue.h` so the include guards make sure that the header has no effect the second time it is being included. This means if `Queue.h` is the first to be included then `Queue` will not yet be declared before it is first used in `EmailSystem.h` which it includes, at this point:

```
Queue<Email> mailbox;
```

I'm guessing, but I find it unlikely that your template `Queue` (if it really is a generic class template) needs to know about `Email` so you should probably remove `#include "EmailSystem.h"` from `Queue.h` to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the Email struct to a separate file and included that.. I needed the Email struct to be included for "template class Queue<Email>;" (as I understand it).

Comment: @cactusbin: If you need an explicit instantiation, then yes both the template and the template parameter need to be complete types at that point.

Answer (score 2):

You `#include "EmailSystem.h"` in Queue.h, before you declare `class Queue`. So when the compiler tries to figure out how to create `struct User`, it has no clue what's the `Queue<Email>` you're trying to use.

Note that EmailSystem.h and Queue.h include each other.